# BigQuery create small sample table all in one query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I know that BigQuery now supports `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT...` like syntax for standard SQL. But does anyone have an example of supplying some sample data to generate this table?

Say I want two columns named **A** and **B**. **A** values should be `1,2,3,4` and **B** values should be `"Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta"`. How can I generate such a query and create such a table? I realize this would not be efficient for creating large tables, but would like to know the recommended method for creating small tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about `select . . . union all`?

```
create table t as
    select 1 as a, 'Alpha' as b union all
    select 2 as a, 'Bravo' as b union all
    select 3 as a, 'Charlie' as b union all
    select 4 as a, 'Delta' as b;
```

Comment: Yes, this works great.Thanks! I just swapped `table t` with the BigQuery syntax of `PROJECT_ID.DATASET_NAME.NEW_TABLE_NAME`

Comment: Additionally, I found a helpful tool to generate much of this query programmatically from data originally in csv format: http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm

Answer (score 10):

Another, less verbose option is

```
CREATE TABLE `PROJECT_ID.DATASET_NAME.NEW_TABLE_NAME` AS  
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT(1 AS a, 'Alpha' AS b),
  (2, 'Bravo'),
  (3, 'Charlie'),
  (4, 'Delta')
])
```

or to make it more easily reused with existing csv

```
CREATE TABLE `PROJECT_ID.DATASET_NAME.NEW_TABLE_NAME` AS  
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT(NULL AS a, '' AS b),
  (1, 'Alpha'),
  (2, 'Bravo'),
  (3, 'Charlie'),
  (4, 'Delta')
])
WHERE NOT a IS NULL
```

Comment: It does not work if there is only one column
```SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT(NULL AS a),
  (1),
  (2),
  (3),
  (4)
])
WHERE NOT a IS NULL
```

Comment: @SergeyLossev it is possible to do this by `UNNEST`ing an array: `SELECT * FROM UNNEST([NULL, 1, 2, 3, 4]) a WHERE NOT a IS NULL`